# How to align HTML checkbox to left when adjusting its size with CSS?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, alignment, size

I'm having some troubles with CSS. In particular, whenever I increase the width of a checkbox, it increases the size of a container around it, moving its alignment away from the start of the page. It is hard to explain, instead I will include a picture below to better detail my problem.

### Here is how I would prefer it to be aligned, but larger:

[image: Screen shot of checkbox aligned correctly]

### And here is how it aligns itself when I increase the width:

[image: Screen shot of larger checkbox but aligned incorrectly]

Again, my goal is to increase the width of the checkbox, while keeping its alignment to the start of the page. I am **not** using any third-party CSS libraries like Bootstrap incase anyone is wondering. I've tried adjusting the margin, text-align, and float CSS attributes with no luck so far. Anyone have any ideas? I'll post the relevant code below.

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=tel],
select {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=tel],
label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  width: 176px;
}

label {
  margin: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 20px;
  width: 176px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Learning Jquery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header">Header</h1>

  <form id="input__form" action="" method="POST">
    <!-- Additional inputs -->
    <label for="input__zip">Zip</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="input__zip" name="input__zip" /><br />
    <label for="input__current__employee">Current Employee</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="input__current__employee" name="input__current__employee" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="input__submit" name="input__submit" value="submit" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a checkbox is always going to bve sqare shape. if you want to increease the size of a check you need to add the 'height'  (samer value as width)

Comment: as @AlvaroMenéndes says, give it a width of 20px for your case , not 176px :)

Comment: Much appreciated everyone, big brain fart moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the width relative to the height
Ex:
Height:20px;
Width:20px;

This is because when you set a height on a square checkbox the width would neeed to be the same or else in theroy it would become a rectangle but the element just does not work that way so it stays a a square, but with sort of a invisible rectangle  around it.

Comment: Well, I feel silly. Shows how long it's been since I've used HTML & CSS. Much appreciated